# Virtualization and hardware incompatible with the host

Tags: windows, linux, virtualization

My main OS is Ubuntu and I virtualize Windows for some apps that are not compatible with Linux.

Now I have a DVB-T TV adapter which is not compatible with Linux.

Is there a way to let Windows see the USB TV adapter while being virtualized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most virtualization software will allow for USB devices to be directly attached to the VM. VirtualBox, for instance requires that you install [the Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) so that USB devices are supported.